# Is a computer program for correspondence theory available?

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-software, modal-logic, software

In the 1990s I some times used a computer program with the Max Planck Institute which helped with calculating complicated correspondences for modal logical formulas. Is some program like that available somewhere now?

Comment: What do you mean by correspondence theory?

Comment: It is the theory which studies the connections between formulas of modal logic and corresponding conditons upon the accessibility relation on "possible worlds" in the model or frame. The term "correspondence theory" is quite established. 

All modal logical formulas have second order correspondences, but in many interesting cases the condition can be shown to collapse to a first order condition. For instance, the formula $\square \alpha \rightarrow \square \square \alpha$ corresponds with the condition that the accessibility relation R is transitive.

Comment: A Google search got me this.  http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schmidt/tools/. Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Jason. Yes, indeed. It was the SCAN-algorithm which is also linked to in your link that I was using, but perhaps some of the other links provided at your site are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question is answered by Jason Rute's link http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schmidt/tools/. Similar links would be welcome.